# Thread 0x0 may have been prematurely finalized with NSOpenPanel in MonoMac

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, monomac

I have problem when there is call to an object of type NSOpenPanel from an action of an object of type NSMenuItem.

My MainController has the next methods, where tblTest is a NSScrollView:

```
        public override void AwakeFromNib ()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib ();
        tblTest.Menu = this.GetContextualMenu ();
    }

    private NSMenu GetContextualMenu ()
    {
        NSMenu menu = new NSMenu ();
        NSMenuItem item = new NSMenuItem ();
        item.Title = "Execute Action";
        item.Activated+= delegate
        {
            NSOpenPanel openPanel= new NSOpenPanel();
            openPanel.Prompt = "Select file";
            openPanel.RunModal();
        };
        menu.AddItem (item);
        return menu;
    }
```

Then when i do click over the Menu item "Execute Action" i get the next exception and the application gets stuck:

```
Native stacktrace:

0   libmono-2.0.dylib                   0x0029ed6f mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 287
1   libmono-2.0.dylib                   0x00203f33 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 355
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94aa859b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bd75e96 _ZN7TFSInfo10InitializeEhP29OpaqueLSSharedFileListItemRef + 770
5   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bcfbf2e _ZN19TFSInfoSynchronizer13FetchChildrenEv + 652
6   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bce7df3 _ZN5TNode19SynchronizeChildrenEmR16TNodeEventPtrSet + 181
7   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bce7867 _ZN5TNode10HandleSyncEm + 2123
8   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bce6fef _ZN5TNode10HandleSyncERK11TCountedPtrI9TNodeTaskERK8TNodePtr + 55
9   DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bd35830 _ZN5TNode17HandleNodeRequestERK11TCountedPtrI9TNodeTaskERKS0_I17TVolumeSyncThreadE + 978
10  DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bd58d7e __PostNodeTaskRequest_block_invoke_010 + 87
11  DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bd6b269 _Z18ExceptionSafeBlockU13block_pointerFvvE + 55
12  DesktopServicesPriv                 0x9bd58d21 __PostNodeTaskRequest_block_invoke_0 + 86
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9b792fc9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9b79494f _dispatch_queue_drain + 224
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9b7947f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 47
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9b793ffc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 187
17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94a52b24 _pthread_wqthread + 346
18  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94a546fe start_wqthread + 30

Debug info from gdb:
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Thread 0x0 may have been prematurely finalized
```

Anyone knows what is happening??

Comment: The interesting part of the error is `[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, which is the managed exception. Now what is causing it is beyond me :)

Comment: @miniBill not all the time happening that i get: [code]
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Thread 0x0 may have been prematurely finalized, so i think it is something with the Garbage Collector, that is generating the problem.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you :(

Comment: @gatm50 I copied your code into a blank MonoMac project and I could not reproduce the crash... Is there something else going on here, perhaps not in your sample code?

Comment: @TheNextman here is the project where i get the error [link](http://sdrv.ms/V5OIea), it is a package with name:TheModalOpenFileDialog

Comment: @gatm50 I ran your sample multiple times with no crashes and no problems... Does the issue occur every time for you?

Comment: @TheNextman the issue occur every time in my mac mini with Lion 10.7.4 and Mono Runtime 2.10.9. But i made a couple of test on my other mac with Snow Leoparp 10.6.7 and i cant reproduce the exception and the crash, like you.

Comment: @gatm50 FYI I have rMBP w/10.8.2 and Mono 2.10.9